# Tightness of Bernstein's inequality and Hoeffding's inequality

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, inequality, distribution-tails

Let $\{ X_t \}$ be independent zero mean random variables, and $|X_t|<R$.
Bernstein's inequality yields:
$$\mathbb{P} \left( \sum_{t=1}^{T}X_{i} \geq \varepsilon \right)
\leq \exp \left( 
\frac{ -\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{2} }{
\sum_{t=1}^{T} \mathbb{E} \left[ X_{t}^{2} \right] +\frac{1}{3}R\varepsilon }
\right).$$
Azuma's inequality (Hoeffding's inequality) yields:
$$\mathbb{P} \left( \sum_{t=1}^{T}X_{t} \geq \varepsilon \right)
\leq \exp \left(
\frac{-\frac12 \varepsilon^{2}}{ TR^2 }
\right).$$
Apparently, for large $\varepsilon$, Hoeffding's inequality is better; while for $\mathrm{var}(X_t)<R^2$ and $\varepsilon<TR$, Bernstein's inequality is better. So Question 1: Is Bernstein/Hoeffding tight? Question 2: Is there any inequality that combines Bernstein+Hoeffding? Q3: Is there any inequality that is tight in both regimes?

Comment: No, they are not tight. For example, Bennett's inequality is always at least as tight as Bernstein's (see Exercise 2.7 of Wainwright's HDS)